# Collapse nested ng-repeat created divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to achieve something like the image below. This is my data:

[image: Nested sections]

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
    .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 

    $scope.showReport = {};
    $scope.toggleShow = function (ym) {
        $scope.showReport[ym] = !$scope.showReport[ym];
    };

    $scope.Reports = [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Report One', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Report Core', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Report Alpha', Year: 2016, Month: 3 },
        { Id: 4, Name: 'Report Moon', Year: 2015, Month: 5 },
        { Id: 5, Name: 'Report Sky', Year: 2015, Month: 2 }
    ];
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports | groupBy: 'Year'">
    {{ key }}
    <ul ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value | groupBy: 'Month'">
        <a ng-click="toggleShow(key+key1)"> O{{key1}} </a>
        <li ng-repeat="p in value1" ng-if="!showReport[key+key1]">
            {{p.Name }} 
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The objective is that if you click on any of the underlined numbers, the reports that belong to that month hide or show (collapsible). That's already done. This must also happen with the years- when you click a year, the months within must show/hide. I have tried many things but it seems I cannot figure it out what I need. I have made a JS BIN where my code is.

http://jsbin.com/huhabehoju/edit?html,js,output

Any help will be kindly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

  <meta name="description" content="[groupBy example]"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainController"> 

   <ul ng-init= "yearhide=false" ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports | groupBy: 'Year'">
     <li ng-click="yearhide = !yearhide">{{ key }}</li>
      <ul ng-hide="yearhide" ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value | groupBy: 'Month'">
     <li ng-click="hideo = !hideo">O{{key1}} 
       <ul> 
        <li ng-show="hideo" ng-repeat="p in value1">
   {{p.Name }} 
       </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[try this jsbin link,here is demo](http://jsbin.com/xoseriyida/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hi thank you so much,, is it possible to order them by descending order? groupby orders them by ascending. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jsbin for you [here](http://jsbin.com/tabexuhuli/1/edit?html,js,output).
I have added a new function that will hide and show the months based on your years.

```
$scope.showYears = {};
  $scope.toggleYear = function(year) {
    if ($scope.showYears[year] === undefined || $scope.showYears[year] === null)
      $scope.showYears[year] = false;
    else $scope.showYears[year] = !$scope.showYears[year];

  }
  $scope.showMonth = function(month, year) {
    if ($scope.showYears[year] === undefined || $scope.showYears[year] === null)
      return true;
    return $scope.showYears[year];
  }
```

The HTML has been kept as

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports | groupBy: 'Year'">
  <div ng-click="toggleYear(key)">YEAR - {{ key }}</div>
  <ul ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value | groupBy: 'Month'" ng-show="showMonth(key1, key)">
<a ng-click="toggleShow(key+key1)"> MONTH - {{key1}} </a>
<li ng-repeat="p in value1" ng-if="!showReport[key+key1]">
     {{p.Name }} 
 </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

I cant see you toggleShow method, so I am assuming that you have already written the logic for that method.

Comment: Hi thank you so much,, is it possible to order them by descending order? groupby orders them by ascending. thanks

Answer (score 1):

can try this one no need to add any function in controller

```
<div>
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports | groupBy: 'Year'"  >
      <span ng-click="hideGroup[key] = !hideGroup[key]" style="cursor:pointer;">{{ key }}- {{value.show}}</span>
      <ul ng-hide="hideGroup[key]"  ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value | groupBy: 'Month'">
         <span ng-click="hideGroup[key+key1] = !hideGroup[key+key1]" style="cursor:pointer;">O{{key1}}</span> 
         <li ng-hide="hideGroup[key+key1]" ng-repeat="p in value1">
            {{p.Name }} 
         </li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Updated:**

`orderBy` works only for array so at first you need to convert it to array. and `orderBy` should be last filter and you need to add `filter` in your controller so inject `$filter` in your controller. can see this example

In Controller:

```
  $scope.Reports= [];//your daata
  $scope.showReport = {};
  $scope.toggleShow = function (ym) {
      $scope.showReport[ym] = !$scope.showReport[ym];
  };
  $scope.desc = function(arr) {
    return $filter('min')
      ($filter('map')(arr, '-Year')); // descending by year
  };
```

in Html:

```
<ul ng-repeat="reports in Reports | groupBy: 'Year' | toArray:true | orderBy:desc">
     <li><span ng-click="toggleShow(reports[0].Year)" style="cursor:pointer">{{ reports[0].Year }}</span></li>
     <ul ng-hide="showReport[reports[0].Year]" ng-repeat="items in reports | groupBy: 'Month'">
          <li><span ng-click="toggleShow(reports[0].Year+items[0].Month)" style="cursor:pointer">O{{items[0].Month}} </span>
               <ul ng-hide="showReport[reports[0].Year+items[0].Month]"> 
                   <li  ng-repeat="item in items">
                           {{item.Name }} 
                   </li>
               </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

**[See Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JarzM0NMSfBECTU6ZeQn?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi, I have tried this one, everything works except the last year, even their months collapse but the year doesnt. here is the js bin with your solution http://jsbin.com/niteru/edit?html,js,output

Comment: in your link working fine for me. can you check again :)

Comment: better to use `[key+key1]` for second repeat create unique. updated. :)

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to order them by descending order? groupby orders them by ascending. thanks

Comment: Possible but need some change. Updated may answer to show year order by desc and then month order by asc. can see updated part @GilbertoQuintero